# Оплатить карточкой / оплатить по карточке

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Я мыслю так: если мы говорим "оплатить деньгами", но никогда не говорим "оплатить по деньгам" - то правильно будет: "оплатить карточкой".

Возможны ли оба варианта, или нужно говорить только "оплатить карточкой"?

Если оба варианта неправильные - тогда как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, произошло смешение понятий. Есть средства платежа (деньги, чеки и т. п.) и есть способы платежа (среди них — использование банковской карты). В сознании потребителей банковская карта превратилась в средствo платежа, так вошло в употребление выражение "оплатить карточкой" по аналогии с "оплатить деньгами". Однако сочетание прижилось — и ничего с этим не поделаешь.

> Для того чтобы сделать серьезное приобретение, потребителю не придется оформлять кредит в магазине-партнере ― покупку можно будет оплатить картой. [События (2004) // «Бизнес-журнал», 2004.03.03]

А употребление выражения "оплатить по карточке" считаю ошибкой.

Answer (score 2):

Глагол "оплатить" подразумевает в том или ином смысле передачу денег из рук в руки. И этот глагол не употребляется с предлогами. "Русская речь в эфире. Комплексный справочник" говорит следующее:

> глагол **оплатить** употребляется всегда без предлога: *оплатить
>   расходы, оплатить труд*, поэтому неправильно говорить: *оплатить
>   за работу, оплатить по долгам;*

**Я мыслю так: если мы говорим "оплатить деньгами", но никогда не говорим "оплатить по деньгам" - то правильно будет: "оплатить карточкой".**

Не думаю, что это правильная аналогия. Вы **оплачиваете что-то с помощью карточки**. А выражение "оплатить карточкой" является сокращением и вряд ли оно нормативно в строгом смысле на сегодняшний день. Но у меня нет сомнений, что оно прочно вошло в русский язык.

**UPD**.
Посмотрите объяснение в конце [этой страницы](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=w4gtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3&source=bl&ots=aGkd2VwflE&sig=q09XmhPiYnw1uaPJ1JuNQJziwMs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD08LIldvaAhWHUlAKHXLKB7AQ6AEIbTAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

И то, и другое - условности. Аналогия с деньгами при объяснении падежа *не проходит*: при оплате расстаются не с карточкой, а с деньгами. Более ясное объяснение можно дать формально употребляемому варианту "**оплатить с карты**" - всё теми же **деньгами**, которые к ней приписаны, но в выражении опущены. В обоих других случаях тоже можно увидеть упрощение. В выражении "оплатить картой" она выступает как *инструмент*, посредством которого *производят оплату*, а к инструменту вполне применим творительный падеж. Варианту "по карте" тоже можно привести оправдание: можно посмотреть на него как на сокращение до одного слова громоздкого понятия "оплатить **по** безналичной **схеме** с использованием банковской карты" (это слово лишь *ссылается* на систему оплаты: *по системе/схеме с картой -> по карте*).