# Вы будете платить по карте?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

...кругом слышатся такие вопросы. В магазинах.

Обратил на это внимание недавно. Разве так нормально говорить? Для мне естественно *платить/оплачивать карт**ой**.*

Comment: Думаю, что все пошло с "оплачивать по системе карточных переводов". Это сократилось до "оплачивать по карте" и закрепилось в языке. Еще можно назвать это фразеологизмом, отвечающим на вопрос "как", как например: "оплачивать по старинке". Но это уход от вопроса о предложно-падежной форме к наречному выражению. Вот когда покарте (или по старинке) станет писаться слитно, тогда другое дело. На письме бы закрепилось "оплачивать посредством карты", но в устной речи все наоборот (то что нормально на письме не нормально в речи и наоборот), вычурные предлоги типа посредством считаются "ненормальными".

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440048/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Пример из книжки: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=L69bATm7nugC&pg=PA233&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U1HmwY0GVn079G1uEpNXi0zmSClsQ&w=1280

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Да, плохо поискал по вопросам.